# Can an SVM be trained to target a scalar value (from 0 to 100) instead of a binary?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I've looked at tutorials on SVMs on YouTube. In each tutorial, the training data is split into discrete groups, usually two (e.g. X's and Y's) rather than a value between some range (1 to 100). The documentation for [svmtrain](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) says the following for the target `Group` argument:

> Grouping variable, which can be a categorical, numeric, or logical
>   vector, a cell vector of strings, or a character matrix with each row
>   representing a class label. Each element of Group specifies the group
>   of the corresponding row of Training. Group should divide Training
>   into two groups.

Again it says two groups. I have training data where an observation (row) is a vector of numbers corresponding to how strongly a frequency was activated for an audio file. I have a target for each observation that is a real number between 1 and 100. I want it so if a similar audio file is tested on the trained data, a similar target number will be produced. But as I understand it, the SVM can only tell me if the new audio file matches or does not match the trained audio file instead of how closely it matches. Am I wrong? Can the SVM be trained to map from a vector to a scalar from 1 to 100 and not just a binary does or does not belong to some group?

If this can be done, how can I do it with the [svmtrain](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) function? Do I just make the `Group` vector row have the 1 to 100 number that the observation row corresponds to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two settings that more or less match your problem.

- Regression, where you try to predict a **real value** and you can use **Support Vector Regression** (SVR) for this.
- Ranking problem, where you are just interested in whether one element induces stronger or weaker reaction than another, and you can use **Ranking Support Vector Machine** (RankSVM) for this.

You could also treat your problem as a simple multi-class classification (for which classic SVM with typical multi-class to binary-class decomposition is applied), however, your classes have structure (as there is natural ordering of them), so the above formulations are better fit.

Answer (score 2):

A classic SVM only does binary classification. This should make sense once you understand what's happening underneath the hood! Each training observation i is an n-dimensional vector x_i along with a binary classification y_i = 1 or y_i = 0. What SVM training tries to do is draw a hyperplane through n-dimensional space to spit your observations x into a half-space that's categorized as y_i=1 and a half-space that's category 0. A hyperplane splits a linear space into half spaces, so a classic SVM can only do binary classification.

Linear regression with ordinary least squares is possibly the simplest thing to try. You can always add non-linear transformations of your data to get more right hand side variables for linear regression. Back on SVM stuff, there may be a way to represent your classification problem as a multiple binary classification problem, but I've never done that so I don't know how easy/hard etc... that is.